# Difference between Directional Derivative x Chain Rule for Scalar Fields

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, scalar-fields

could you guys help me out with an issue I am having.

1. What's the difference between the "Directional Derivative" and "Chain Rule for Scalar Fields"? In **meaning** and the **formulae**?

I don't know if I got it right but both of them have the same formula:

$$ g'(\vec{r(t)}) = \nabla(g(t)) \cdot  \vec{r'(t)}    \ for \ the \ Chain \ Rule$$

**And**

$$ Derivative = \nabla (g(t)) \cdot \vec{r(t)}  \ for \ the \ Directional\ Derivative$$

And **to me** they both seem to have the same meaning, since when we use the chain rule, we are using a vector whose direction is defined by the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of directional derivatives is actually a consequence of the chain rule, but it only applies when $f$ is differentiable at $t$. However, it’s not the fundamental definition of a directional derivative, which can exist even when the function isn’t differentiable. For example, $f(x,y)=(x^2y)^{1/3}$ has a directional derivative in every direction at the origin, but is not differentiable there.

The fundamental definition of a directional derivative looks very much like the definition of an ordinary derivative: $$D_{\mathbf v}f(\mathbf x) = \lim_{h\to0}{f(\mathbf x+h\mathbf v) - f(\mathbf x)\over h}.$$ Note that the partial derivatives that you’re no doubt familiar with are actually special cases of directional derivatives. It’s a theorem that when $f$ is differentiable at $\mathbf x$, then $D_{\mathbf v}f(\mathbf x)=\nabla f(\mathbf x)\cdot\mathbf v$. Geometrically, this is because differentiability implies the existence of a tangent (hyper)plane to the graph, and the directional derivative is then just the slope of this plane in the direction of $\mathbf v$.

Comment: Could I say then that:

The Chain Rule in multivariable Calculus allows us to find out the derivative of a function related to a parameter "t" that will define a direction in which we would like to calculate the variation of the function.

Since it is NECESSARY to have a parameter "t" to define a direction, every Directional Derivative needs to make use of the ChainRule to be calculated.

Comment: @Paulo_Martin I disagree. I’ve shown you a way to compute directional derivatives that doesn’t involve the chain rule. Moreover, the chain rule is only applicable where $f$ is differentiable (neglecting that condition is a common mistake made by students), but directional derivatives can exist at point where that doesn’t hold.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand, but can't I always parametrise the function "v"?

I don't get one thing. We can have a directional derivative even with a function "f" that is not differentiable. So, if I parametrise another function that describes the direction desired, won't that equation work?

I am using Apostol's book but I think I am not getting the gist of it. I don't really understand why it HAS to be differentiable to apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the derivative (both cases) of a composition 
$\mathbb R^1\stackrel{r}\to\mathbb R^n\stackrel{g}\to\mathbb R^1$ defined by
$g\circ r(t)=g(r(t)$ to get $g'(r(t))\cdot r'(t)$ or in classical notation
$$\frac{dg\circ r}{dt}(t)=\nabla g(r(t))\cdot r'(t),$$
which is a particular instance of the general cases $\mathbb R^1\stackrel{r}\to\mathbb R^n\stackrel{G}\to\mathbb R^m$,
that also comply a chain rule but, for $G'$ one has a matrix $m\times n$.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a case in which it is not a composition if you may?

Comment: maybe you already know that if $b\in\mathbb R^n$ then the directional derivative $\nabla g\cdot b=b^1\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^1}+...+b^n\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^n}$ measures how $g$ varies in the direction $b$...